# How do I get these two columns to have the same height at all times - CSS?

Tags: css

I know I can set the `height` attribute statically in the stylesheet, but that's not what I want to do.

What I want is, since the height of the left column `class=content` will change dynamically (based on the content that is generated) I want the height of the `sidebar` column to also change - even though there is no content being dynamically generated there.

How do I do that?

[Here is the implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/pTKd2/) (in the real version, both columns are directly beside each other, but because of JSFiddle's smaller viewing window it is not).

**Edit1**

I would rather it be achieved with CSS only...no JS (if possible).

Thanks.

Comment: Is the content generated once, or is it updated? If the content stays as it is, then it's a simple css solution, but if not, then not. css is static, only js is dynamic.

Comment: Yeh...the content is generated on each page load. So I guess you can say dynamic...although I imagine that if I were using something like SCSS, LESS or some other CSS framework that allowed me to initiate variables, I could set the height of the `div` that way...but I am just using vanilla CSS for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JS/Jquery based modification:
http://jsfiddle.net/pTKd2/3/

Comment: this help?  http://abcoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/css-equal-height-three-column-layout.html

Comment: Hrmm...that solution looks intriguing, except that I can't figure out how it works. There is some funky stuff done with the `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom`...but other than that...can't quite understand it.

Comment: I really do like this solution, i.e. the JS one, and it works...but if I can get a CSS version, would really love that.

Comment: the css is a bit odd on the example I found, but it works with just css.  The jquery approach is far simpler and cleaner however.

Comment: Definitely agree...if there is a CSS solution that is as elegant as the JS solution, that's kinda what I am looking for.